# Free/Open Source program to share a USB device (e.g. a scanner)

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, usb

Is there an Open Source or Free functional program to make it able to share a USB device (e.g. a scanner) from a Windows XP to a Windows 7?

Comment: There are other ways to share a scanner, but I only know the [USB/IP project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) to share USB devices.  Unfortunately only the client side is available for Windows (the server side, to run on the machine where you connect the USB device to, is only available for linux it seems).

Comment: The way this question is worded makes it sound like a product recommendation, which is off-topic to this site and can get it closed. Instead of asking for a recommendation of a software that does something, it is better asking "I have a problem X, what are possible solutions"